# how to get rid of Reverse Landscape in an Android App?

Tags: android, orientation

I'm trying to make a camera app & trying to always keep the capture button on the bottom of the screen (near navigation buttons), in Portrait and Landscape everything is fine but in Reverse Landscape it ends up on the top of the phone as there's no way to make a Reverse Landscape Activity.

So is there any way to solve this problem? I'm sure there is as all default camera apps have capture button near navigation key, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Check the device orientation in `onConfigurationChanged` and show/hide a different button depending on if its landscape or reverse landscape.

Comment: @KaneO'Riley thanks, it worked

Comment: I'm glad, I've posted my comment as an answer, so if it's solved your question please vote and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the device orientation in `onConfigurationChanged` and show/hide a different button depending on if its landscape or reverse landscape.